# LastModified Date not getting updated in azure Meta DataActivity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a dataset which points to a Azure Blob Container.Every week one file will be saved in the container .I have created a metadata activity pointing to this data set inside a pipeline. But i am not getting the updated  lastModified date inside MetaData .I am using this date in order to check if any new files has coming in the container folder.Inputs please

Comment: I am pointing to Container and not to the files.I can't generate the file name.So i use foreach loop activity to process all the files inside the container.

Comment: Don't get why you deleted `useful` comment. You need further help? Any concern,please let me know. If the answer is helpful,please scan this SO rules:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If the file does comes into container every week once indeed,you could consider using `modifiedDatetimeStart` and `modifiedDatetimeEnd` configurations in the GetMetaData Activity.

For example:

[image]

Based on the statement in the official document:

[image]

you will get the match file names array:

[image]

Then get the file name in the ForEach Activity by using `@item().name`:

[image]

Please note that `modifiedDatetimeStart` and `modifiedDatetimeEnd` could be dynamic content so that you could configure them by using parameters.

Comment: @user3035090 You're so kind,if you think the answer has benefits for you,would you please accept it(the hook beside answer). Thank you!